# Can anything be said about convexity of this function?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, multivariable-calculus

I have the following optimization problem, to find the Excess Mass of for a given $t \ge 0$

$EM(t) = \sup_{u \ge 0}\  \mathbb{P}\Big[s(X) \ge u\Big] - t \cdot Leb\ (\{s \ge u\})$

where,
$s:R^d \to R^+$ is a scoring function
$X$ is a random variable from a distribution
$f$ be the PDF of the above-said distribution
$s \ge u$ is the level set of $s$ at level $u$
$Leb$ is the Lebesgue measure

I was wondering if anything can be commented on the convexity of the function. i.e., positive, negative, or could be anything?

Basically, my main objective is to improve the time complexity (keeping the $t$ fixed) using binary search over linear search if anything could be commented on that.
Even if generalizing is not possible, what could be the conditions for which the function is concave/convex?

I have tried plotting it on a few datasets ($X$) and scoring functions ($s$) and always found the graphs concave upwards. So, in this case, the maximum lies at the end.
Although I need some theoretical backing to make a statement conclusively.

Reference: [On Anomaly Ranking and Excess-Mass Curves](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v38/goix15.pdf)

**Edit:** I plotted $EM_t(u)$ vs $u$ by keeping the $t$ fixed.

Comment: I think i'm misunderstanding the question. If $t_1<t_2$ then for any $u$ we have $\mathbb P[s(X)\geq u]-t_1\text{Leb}(\{s\geq u\})\geq \mathbb P[s(X)\geq u]-t_2\text{Leb}(\{s\geq u\})$ hence the function is decreasing in $t$. You said in your plots it curves upwards?

Comment: @SmallDeviation The curve I plotted was for $EM_t(u)$ vs $u$ by keeping the $t$ fixed.